# Pull spcific piece of data from a page in Node JS

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, google-cloud-functions

I need to web scrape a page, and get a specific piece on info from a Firebase Cloud Function (Which is written in Node JS). I'm using request promise to get the page, but I'm having trouble parsing the data, and getting a spcific string.

The HTML data looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
 <meta name="robots" content="nofollow" />
  <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="images/favicon.ico"/>

   SYSTEM_LOCALE = 'en_US';

   includeStylesheet('school');
   sessionId='-diohWdLrdq75vUF-Gtd_dM0340QRKkPgHCbHKLS';

  <script src="js/analyticsCore.js?version=6.0.0.10.924" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <style type="text/css">
```

What I want to get is the session ID, which changes every time the page is loaded. I can save this page to a variable, but I don't know how to search for the session ID, and save it to a different variable. I think I could do it, if I could figure out how to save the HTML as a string, but .toString() didn't work.

Any Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In general you use cheerio for this, but a simple regex works for this one:

```
text.match(/sessionId='(.*)'/)[1]
```